# Where is the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos(nx)}{n}$ pointwise convergent?

Tags: trigonometric-series

Where is the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos(nx)}{n}$ pointwise convergent?
I tried to apply the Dirichlet's test but I couldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you find trouble in applying it? *Hint* Find a closed form for $$\sum_{k=0}^n\cos kx$$ that let's you decided when this sum is bounded.  A good idea might be to note this is $$\Re\left(\sum_{k=0}^n e^{ikx}\right)$$

Comment: If $x=0$ the partial sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{ikx}$ is divergent but I don't have any clue when $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @Chilote It's a geometric series with ratio $q=e^{ix}$.

Comment: But in that case the ratio is of modulus 1 and a geometric series only converge when the ratio is strictly smaller than 1.

Comment: @Chilote We're not looking for convergence, but boundedness.

Comment: Oh! that's true! So this settles the convergence of the series for all $x\neq 2k\pi$. And what about the values of the series? Is there any familiar function which represent the values of the series?

Comment: @Chilote Yes, it's the Fourier series of... (Claude wasn't entirely incorrect)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Following Pedro Tamaroff, may be, you could consider two summations $$I=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos(nx)}{n}$$ $$J=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin (nx)}{n}$$ Then $$I+iJ=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{inx}}{n}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{y^{n}}{n}=-\log (1-y)$$ where $y=e^{ix}$ and use the real part of the complex logarithm.

Comment: Unless you know that the sums converge pointwise, the expression $I+iJ$ has no sense.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I just wanted to give a possible track. Cheers.

Comment: The taylor series of $-\log(1-y)$ is only valid for $|y|<1$!